# how to readJSON from var in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fo7a.png)

```
// @Library('dxy-shared-library') _
```

pipeline {
agent any
// parameters {
//     text defaultValue: ''''{"a": 1, "b": [1, 2, 3]}'''', name: 'meta'
// }

```
stages {
    stage('Hello') {
        steps("Git Checkout") {
            echo 'Hello World'
            echo "${meta}"
            script {
                def props = readJSON text: meta;
                println props
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: net.sf.json.JSONException: Invalid JSON String
at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:143)
at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:103)
at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:84)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.json.ReadJSONStepExecution.doRun(ReadJSONStepExecution.java:87)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.AbstractFileOrTextStepExecution.run(AbstractFileOrTextStepExecution.java:29)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

pipeline {
agent any

```
stages {
    stage('Hello') {
        steps("Git Checkout") {
            echo 'Hello World'
            echo "${meta}"
            script {
                def props = readJSON text: meta.replace("'", "");
                println props
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}